# showing transparent overlay on listbox

Tags: wpf

we have a requirement where in , we need to have a list box, with some list items , assuming this would be my bottom layer , on top of this,we need a layer which shows up transparent element at some specified positions.

i am on WPF 3.5.

hope i am clear
Thanks In Advance

Deepak

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="50" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Red" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="8" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Oskar ,but with this my listbox items would be unaccessible. i would like my items to drag within and across list boxes.